# Android - Get Text From Website, Loaded On A WebView

Tags: android, eclipse, text, webview, sdk

How to get text from a website, say "www.example.in/file.**txt**". This page is loaded in a webview. I need to get the text from the webpage. I have no Idea.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you know the file URL,just `getInputStream` by `HttpURLConnection`.

Secondly,if you just see the file in a webview. use `Webview.getUrl()` to get the URL.Then,turn to the first.